# Eclipse EGIT - all committed, pulled, merged, marked as merged, still on push I get "rejected - non-fast forward", what am I missing?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm starting to experiment with Git, and I'm sure I'm missing something, as I can't do a simple merge and push

Here is what I do (I probably got it in the wrong order, or wrong in any order, please correct if it is)

- pull
- Syncronize Workspace
- on conflicts - did a manual merge,
- then "Mark as Merged" (is it necessary?)
- on the rest - allowed the automatic merge
- commit my changes
- pressed push (origin-master)
- I get the famous **"rejected - non-fast forward"**
- did a "fetch" to check - nothing to update
- did another commit - nothing to commit

What am I missing?

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm using Windows 7, EGit (1.3.0.201202151440-1) in Eclipse Indigo (SR2, build 20120216-1857) and pushing to GitHub

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I found it, instead of "Mark as Merged", I need to do "Add"

> Manual conflict resolution
>
> To resolve a conflict you have to do the following steps:
>
> Navigate to the conflicting resource Edit the content of the conflicting resource Tell EGit that the conflict is resolved with **Team -> Add**
>
> Commit the conflict resolution with **Team > Commit**

from http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Manual_conflict_resolution

**Edit:** apparently, I should have learned git command line before playing with EGit, same concept there

Comment: Looks like `Add` has been renamed to `Add to Index`

Comment: @arun Thanks for writing this. I was searching for "Add" in "Team".

Comment: as of today, this isn't working for me. the egit synchronize view is stubbornly displaying a conflict, despite multiple attempts to `add to index` and `merge` and `mark as merged`. I guess one of these actions foobarred it. my solution finally was to go to the Git Repository, select the local branch and do `Synchronize with workspace`, and then try to merge it again.