# Pull operation does not make effects after "mark as merged"

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a problem with Eclipse and EGit.

I have a file that has some conflicts.
I tried to merge it manually, and after this operation I tried to click "mark as merged".

So I pull, but the pull doesn't have any effect.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

"Mark a merged" means the file is locally modified.

If the pull was done before, a new pull won't do anything (the remote code was already fetched), and the conflicted merge has just been resolved.

You should [add that file to the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526026/6309), commit and push, not pull.
See "[How to resolve conflicts in egit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914508/6309)" as an example.

Comment: but add to index does not make effects, the file still remains marked as a conflict. Furthermore, I have some other new files that are to be pulled, but egit does not pull them.

Comment: @AlessandroC If you remove the merge markers inside that file, it won't be marked as a conflict anymore